# Wordpress lunch menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display a weekly menu on a wordpress site. I am using an old plugin that should do it; the problem is when I add 2 weeks, let's say week 40 and 41. When the week changes to 41 it still displays week 40. If I delete week 40 it will display week 41.

I think this is the code that does it.

```
function widget($args, $instance) {
        // Setup widget display elements
        global $tm_lunch_menu_days, $tm_lunch_menu_months;
        $before_widget = $after_widget = $before_title = $after_title = '';
        extract($args, EXTR_IF_EXISTS);
        // Retrieve additional settings
        $settings = get_option('tm_lunch_menu_settings');
        // Prepare query
        $today = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j'), date('Y'));
        $start = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j')-7, date('Y'));
        $end = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j')+(7*$settings['weeks']), date('Y'));
        $query_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'tm_lunch_menu',
            'numberposts' => $instance['numberposts'],
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'meta_query' => array( array(
                'key' => '_tm_lunch_timestamp',
                'value' => array($start, $end),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            ))
        );
        // Retrieve menus
        $menus = get_posts($query_args);
        if($menus || $settings['no_menu'] == 'display') {
            // Start widget output
            echo $before_widget;
            echo $before_title.$instance['title'].$after_title;
            // Process menus
            if($menus) {
                foreach($menus as $menu) {
                    $x=0; $y=7;
                    // Get menu info
                    $timestamp = get_post_meta($menu->ID, '_tm_lunch_timestamp', true);
                    $items = get_post_meta($menu->ID, '_tm_lunch_menu_day', true);
                    $start_day = date('w', $timestamp);
                    // While day of week is less than number of days in week
                    while($x < $y) {
                        if((in_array($start_day, $settings['days']) && !empty($items[$start_day])))
                        if(($instance['show_partial'] == 1 && ($today <= ($timestamp + (86400 * $x)))) || $instance['show_partial'] == 0) {
                            if(!$settings['format']) $settings['format'] = '%l, %M %d';
                            $week_day = date('w', $timestamp + (86400 * $x));
                            $month = date('n', $timestamp + (86400 * $x));
                            $day = date('j', $timestamp + (86400 * $x));
                            $tmp = str_replace('%F', $tm_lunch_menu_months[$month], $settings['format']);
                            $tmp = str_replace('%M', substr($tm_lunch_menu_months[$month], 0, 3), $tmp);
                            $tmp = str_replace('%l', $tm_lunch_menu_days[$week_day], $tmp);
                            $tmp = str_replace('%D', substr($tm_lunch_menu_days[$week_day], 0, 3), $tmp);
                            $tmp = str_replace('%d', $day, $tmp);
                            echo '<strong>'.$tmp.'</strong><br />';
                            echo $items[$start_day].'<br/>';
                        }
                        $x++;
                        $start_day = ($start_day < 6)? $start_day+1 : 0;
                    }
                }
            } else echo '<p>'.$settings['no_menu_msg'].'</p>';
```

Comment: And which plugin is this that you are using? (Name AND a url / link, please)

Comment: Tm lunch menu, https://wordpress.org/plugins/tm-lunch-menu/
I have tried to edit the $start and $end but im not really getting what it is doing.